# The range of int in Java

Tags: java, integer, range

I understand that the *int* range in Java should be -2^31 to 2^31-1.

But when I run this code snippet with 20:

```
public class Factorial {
    public int factorial(int n) {
        int fac=1;
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            fac *= i;
            System.out.println("Factorial of " + i + " is: " + fac);
        }
        return fac;
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Factorial of 1 is: 1
Factorial of 2 is: 2
Factorial of 3 is: 6
Factorial of 4 is: 24
Factorial of 5 is: 120
Factorial of 6 is: 720
Factorial of 7 is: 5040
Factorial of 8 is: 40320
Factorial of 9 is: 362880
Factorial of 10 is: 3628800
Factorial of 11 is: 39916800
Factorial of 12 is: 479001600
Factorial of 13 is: 1932053504
Factorial of 14 is: 1278945280
Factorial of 15 is: 2004310016
Factorial of 16 is: 2004189184
Factorial of 17 is: -288522240
Factorial of 18 is: -898433024
Factorial of 19 is: 109641728
Factorial of 20 is: -2102132736
```

It's not making sense from 13 (13! = 6,227,020,800). It looks like it's out of range and wrapped around. What's wrong? Is it due to [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) that I'm using?

Though I think it's not relevant, here is the test code:

```
public class TestFac {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input num you want to factorial: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        Factorial fac = new Factorial();
        fac.factorial(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: use **long** datatype instead of int.

Comment: You should first check the actual value of factorial 13 and see if it fits within 0 and 2^31 -1. Cannot blame Eclipse or Java for the mistake. Like the answers posted, go for long or even better BigInteger.

Comment: Well, [2^31-1 is 2 147 483 647](https://www.google.com/search?q=2%5E31-1) and [13! is  6 227 020 800](https://www.google.com/search?q=2%5E31-1) which is *bigger*.

Comment: bigInteger http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 26):

Here I would like to mention the concept of integer clock.

The maximum and minimum values for int in Java are:

```
int MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
int MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
```

Please check the following results

```
 int a = 2147483645;
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    System.out.println("a:" + a++);
 }
```

Output:

```
a:2147483645
a:2147483646
a:2147483647
a:-2147483648
a:-2147483647
a:-2147483646
a:-2147483645
a:-2147483644
a:-2147483643
a:-2147483642
```

It shows that when you go beyond the limit of the +ve range of integer, the next values starts from its negative starting value again.

```
 -2147483648,       <-----------------
 -2147483647,                        |
 -2147483646,                        |
  .                                  |
  .                                  |
  .                                  |    (the next value will go back in -ve range)
  0,                                 |
 +1,                                 |
 +2,                                 |
 +3,                                 |
  .                                  |
  .                                  |
  .,                                 |
 +2147483645,                        |
 +2147483646,                        |
 +2147483647     ---------------------
```

If you calculate the factorial of 13 it is 6227020800.
This value goes beyond the int range of java.
So the new value will be

```
        6227020800
      - 2147483647 (+ve max value)
   -----------------
Value = 4079537153
      - 2147483648 (-ve max value)
   -----------------
value = 1932053505
   -             1  (for zero in between -ve to +ve value)
  ----------------
Answer = 1932053504
```

So, in your answer, the factorial of 13 is becoming 1932053504. This is how integer clock works.

You can use long datatype instead of integer to achieve your purpose.

Comment: The same problem will happen with long datatype (with value bigger than long MAX_VALUE) ... to limit this error Use BigInteger class instead

Comment: What do you mean by *"integer clock"* and *"the +ve range of integer"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I assume +ve and -ve mean positive and negative, although I've never seen these abbreviations before.

Answer (score 3):

From *[Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*:

> The `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use long instead.

Moral of the story: Never believe in your teacher blindly!

Comment: Actual moral of the story: listen to your teacher *closely*. What he says, *might just be correct*. What information did the teacher give you that was wrong? From what you posted, only your interpretation seems wrong.

Comment: You are right. I mistook 10 power and 2 power... Silly mistake indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Please run this code:

```
System.out.println("Minimum value of Integer is: " + Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println("Maximum value of Integer is: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

So you can see why it fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you check Java Integer, its maximum and minimum values are as follows:

```
int    MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
int    MIN_VALUE = -2147483648
```

If you do some maths, you will see that (factorial of 13) `1932053504 * 14` is `27048749056` which is beyond int [MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE) and that's why you are getting the wrong result for the factorial of 14. So in order to have good results it is better to use the `long` type instead.

Answer (score 1):

Factorial 13 is 6227020800.  This is more than 31 bits long, so it's wrapped around.

If you want to support *big* numbers (e.g., arbitrary length) then consider using the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class which provides an unlimited range.